# LOAD DATA query error

Tags: load-data-infile, phpquery

What is the problem with this line

```
$load ="LOAD DATA INFILE $inputFile INTO TABLE $tableName FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES";

echo $load;

mysql_query($load);
```

The echo  result is;

```
LOAD DATA INFILE appendpb.csv INTO TABLE appendpb_csv FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

The error is;

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'appendpb.csv INTO TABLE appendpb_csv FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED B' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MYSQL LOAD DATA Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) it should have single quotes around the input file:

```
$load ="LOAD DATA INFILE '$inputFile' INTO TABLE $tableName FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES";
```

Eventually looking likes this

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'appendpb.csv' INTO TABLE appendpb_csv FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Assuming the path of the file is correct.